# How to retrive email from MS Exchange server on Android

Tags: exchange-server, android

I’ve been googling for a couple of days now! I’m looking at a way of integrating simple mail functions into my android app. A few people have suggested looking at K9 which I have done. This is obviously a fully featured mail client and has far more functionality than I need. I wanted to know whether there was a way using Android API's to connect and retrieve mail?

Any responses greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, afaik are no Android APIs you can use for this purpose. You could use the [ActiveSync protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) to connect to the Exchange server and pull down the email messages you need.

Answer (score 3):

There are third party API called JWebServices / JWebDAV . As far as I know they both working on Android