# Java EWS can't send TimeZoneDefintion

Tags: android, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm trying to create event using Java EWS.

As I understand, there's a bug in Microsoft's code with `TimeZoneDefention` class
I would like to know if someone managed to solve the problem? If there's workaround or something that can help me pass the timezone from my application to the server?

Comment: I used EWS managed API with c# and it send TimeZoneDefinition in Soap request correctly.'<t:TimeZoneContext>
        <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="India Standard Time" />
      </t:TimeZoneContext>'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956262/how-to-retrive-email-from-ms-exchange-server-on-android/13775447#13775447

Comment: thanks, but i need it with Java not C#, I know that C# works, the problem is with Java.

Comment: Sharas- Did you get the answer for this? please share.