# Using Exchange Webservices in Office 365 Starter Android Project

Tags: java, android, office365, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm trying to create an Android app to book meeting rooms through Office 365. I've started with this tutorial (https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Android-Start). It's up and running, and I can connect to my outlookuser with it. But it is far too comprehensive for what my needs are, so I've stripped it down to only having the calendar function.

I've created some room resources (or room mailboxes if you wish) in exchange online and want to be able to book these with the tools that are in the Exchange Webserives Java API (https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api). Thing is, it can't seem to set credentials or service (it says I'm possibly missing an import, but trying `import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data;`only gives me an error on the import) as they do in that first part:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("emailAddress", "password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
```

Could be that I'm way off here, but isnt Exchange Online a part of Office365 and should therefore be able to create the service without any further imports than the ones in the first project?

Comment: There is alternative third party EWS API for Android

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956262/how-to-retrive-email-from-ms-exchange-server-on-android/13775447

Answer (score 0):

The library `ews-java-api` is currently undergoing a major refactoring, if your checked out version is not older than a month, you can try out these classes.

```
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
```

Hope this helps.