# Exchange Web Service JAVA API (EWS-JAVA-API)

Tags: java, android, apache, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I prepared a whole text to paste in there but since a message can't contain more than two links due to my newbiness. I am gonna give you a link to the original message: http://pastebin.com/bBmSc2Yb

Long story short, I tried to use EWS-JAVA-API on Android without any success even tough I tried this:

-Build EWS-JAVA-API and use it *without* and *with* distant dependencies in my Android project

I tried to add same files used at compilation in the same's order as the pom.xml one. And I fixed conflits error by editing the build.gradle file. Please see in the PasteBin's link to see error message.

-Used a remote EWS-JAVA-API (from sonartype) *without* and *with* remote dependencies from mavenCentral().

-I tried alose with compiled libraires imported in local.

**I have to access to appointements**, contacts and so on. I need to use a library which implement those functions.

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0. And the target version of Android is 4.3 minimum and the terminal I am using an Android 4.4.2's terminal (Samsung Galaxy S5 mini).

Does anyone manage to successly to do something with **this** library ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956262/how-to-retrive-email-from-ms-exchange-server-on-android/13775447#13775447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, WMWare,

I tried out the JWebService, I get it working.

You should use an AsyncTask (as in login activities) to make it work.

Don't forget to put Internet access in your manifest.

Here's an example's code (thanks to Rade from the support):

Hi fellow,

Thanks, WMWare,

I tried out the JWebService, I get it working.

You should use an AsyncTask (as in login activities) to make it work.

Don't forget to put Internet access in your manifest.

Here's an example's code (thanks to Rade from the support):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.independentsoft.exchange.Appointment;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Body;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Folder;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.ItemId;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Service;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.ServiceException;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.StandardFolder;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s=postData(params);
            return s;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

        }

        public String postData(String valueIWantToSend[]) {

            String returnValue = "";
            try {
                Service service = new Service("https:192.168.2.105/ews/Exchange.asmx", "John","xxxxx");

                Folder inboxFolder = service.getFolder(StandardFolder.INBOX);

                Log.w("inboxFolder", inboxFolder.getDisplayName());

                returnValue = inboxFolder.getDisplayName();

            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Log.w("ServiceException", ":" + ex.getFaultCode());
                Log.w("ServiceException", ":" + ex.getFaultString());
                Log.w("ServiceException", ":" + ex.getMessage());
                Log.w("ServiceException", ":" + ex.getXmlMessage());
                Log.w("ServiceException", ":" + ex.getResponseCode());
                Log.w("ServiceException", ":" + ex.getRequestBody());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.w("Exception", ex.getMessage());
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```